# 1920x1080 hd/4k screen - perfect size website content going off screen?

Tags: html, css, windows, screen, monitor

I am doing a project for somebody who is displaying content on screens around their venue.

The screen size is 1920x1080 pixels (and I think they're using HD/4k laptop hooked up via HDMI).

I have built the page to exactly that size (1920x1080) and using screen size emulators, my large iMac screen with the browser size reduced to 1920x1080 it is working perfectly. However, on their laptop screen the content is going beyond the screen size, any ideas whether it has something to do with HD/4k, resolution settings or anything?

Comment: Are they sure about their screensize? A laptop with that resolution is a rare thing. Plus it should work if you are %100 sure that the size of your page is given amount.

Comment: Did you consider that browser window has borders?

Comment: Hi guys,
I am making the browser windows full screen so it has nothing to do with the content. I have also just tried plugging my HD tv in, using 1920x1080 resolution and that works perfectly too.

Comment: Can you posts screenshots?

Comment: Check the screen resolution, if a monitor supports xy res it doesn't mean that they set it up properly to max res. Maybe they are just using a wrong res on the screen or are mirroring the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

> However, on their laptop screen the content is going beyond the screen
>   size, any ideas whether it has something to do with HD/4k, resolution
>   settings or anything?

An idea to test/possibly fix this is to use [viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) and then verifying what the browser on the venue screen says the resulting size is. Inspector is great for these sorts of things. If you come up with more information about the situation/context (like screenshots), then I'd love for you to keep us updated.

Right off the bat, it'd be difficult to diagnose the issue without any information about the devices involved, their specs, the browser being used to display the work, etc.

Please feel free to consult the included link.

Comment: I think their laptop screen isn't setup correctly because although the screen size is 1920x1080 I think the aspect ratio or something isn't correct. They connected the TVs and used dual screen and surprise surprise it worked perfectly. Panic over! Thank you!